# Python Classes Dataframe Syntax Highlighting bug

Tags: python, dataframe, class, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know what's going on here with the syntax highlighting when you use Dataframes with an arrow like this at the end of a Class definition, making everything one colour (yellow)?

It also seems to mess with one of my module calls.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVM i found the solution. It was a bad extension here > https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tht13.python